# Inno setup PrivilegesRequiredOverridesAllowed: Different paths for administrative and non-administrative

Tags: inno-setup

I want my Inno setup to be able to be run in administrative mode as well as in non-administrative. Therefore I am setting

```
PrivilegesRequiredOverridesAllowed=dialog
```

The setup installs an Inventor addin for all versions, so according to https://help.autodesk.com/view/INVNTOR/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-52422162-1784-4E8F-B495-CDB7BE9987AB the paths would be:

- %ProgramData%\Autodesk\Inventor Addins\, or
- %AppData%\Autodesk\Inventor 20xx\Addins\

Now what to specify in `DefaultDirName`, in order to copy my files to `{app}`?